# CNTK Semantic Object Detection?

Tags: python, cntk

So there is the Kitti format, which digits uses.  This is documented here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/digits/extensions/data/objectDetection/README.md#label-format

From the sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Image/Regression/RegrSimple_CIFAR10.cntk it appears as though I need to stack deserializers to accomplish the goal.  OK, so this is good for 1 object class per image, but what about an instance where I have many objects or a known set of objects per image?

I would imagine there would be a need to move to a format similar to Kitti.  Does this currently exist?  Is there a way to stack deserializers to do this?  As it currently stands with the regression sample, I would be unable to create a shared set of feature extractors across many bounding box outputs (more reasons than just labels, but just focusing on labels here).

The question is likely to come up, why do I not use the Fast RCNN demo?  Because that uses ROI and that ROI is sent for classification, the issue is that my object classes change depending on the semantics of where they are in the image and what is around them.  Fast RCNN then merges the boxes together as a master prediction.  This does not work for my scenario.

Thanks!

EDITS - Thoughts on progressing forward
Maybe I just need a text deserializer entirely…

|File1Path node1 node2 node3 node4

|File2Path node1 node2 node3 node4

Now the question then becomes what if each file has n objects in it?  Fast R-CNN has this type of complex scenario.   Does it just stack the next 4 nodes after the first 4 for each class such as below?

|File1Path x1 y1 x2 y2 x21 y21 x22 y22

Now if I do that, then the question is, how does the reader know which file this goes to?

Does the file name become the sequence Id I suppose?

FilePath1 |apple x1 y1 x2 y2 x21 y21 x22 y22 |banana x1 y1 x2 y2

FilePath2 |orange x1 y1 x2 y2 x21 y21 x22 y22 |banana x1 y1 x2 y2

I think the above is exactly what I need, the question then I suppose is, is there a sample reader for a format like this in python?  The Fast R-CNN is only in brain script currently.  I think what I might be able to do is feed the entire input convolutional feature map into the ROI proposals and this will yield a semantic object detection network for whatever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Could you think of your data similar to the data shown in the [language understanding tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_202_Language_Understanding.ipynb) where some labels can be sparsely coded such as apples and banana's and oranges. Not all file path will have all three. Suggest that you refer to the tutorial for insights.